# Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless not recognized in USB Live install of 13.10 on Dell 6400 Laptop

Tags: wireless, dell, broadcom, 13.10

Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless not recognized in USB Live install of 13.10 on Dell 6400 Laptop

Hardware: Dell Laptop 6400 1.66 GHz and 2GB RAM

USB Live created with a 4 GB persistent file.

Upon startup I get a functional Ethernet WIRED connection and Bluetooth but no indications of a wireless service.

There is no hardware switch for the wireless as on some laptops.  The soft switch (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) toggles the Bluetooth on and off but the wireless indicator never lights up.

When probing around, this is what I find:

```
**rfkill list** //is it being killed?  No, wireless not even listed  
0: hci0: Bluetooth  
        Soft blocked: no   
        Hard blocked: no  

**iwconfig** // look specifically at the parameters of the wireless network  
    lo        no wireless extensions.  
    eth0      no wireless extensions.  

**ifconfig** // look at interface configurations  
>eth0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:b9:4c:cf:b3    
>          inet addr:192.168.1.4  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0   
>          inet6 addr: fe80::219:b9ff:fe4c:cfb3/64 Scope:Link  
>          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
>          RX packets:3826 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0   
>          TX packets:2033 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
>          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000  
>          RX bytes:3944231 (3.9 MB)  TX bytes:197816 (197.8 KB)  
>          Interrupt:17  

>lo       Link encap:Local Loopback  
>          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0  
>          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host  
>          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1  
>          RX packets:264 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
>          TX packets:264 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
>          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0  
>          RX bytes:26685 (26.6 KB)  TX bytes:26685 (26.6 KB)  

**lspci -k | grep -A2 Network** //Hardware and Driver  
>0b:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)  
>   Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card  
>   Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge  

>**cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf | grep -B1 bcm** //check what's blacklisted  
>    # replaced by b43 and ssb.  
>    blacklist bcm43xx
```

Do you have any ideas on how to get this working?

I have searched the previous questions and have tried several of the answers offered -- but no joy.  It looks like these cards have been a problem for almost every release of Ubuntu and it seems that with every release there is a different twist that must be used to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a working ethernet connection, please do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

I know you said you removed it, but let's be doubly certain. Then do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

You should be all set.

Comment: It's working!  Thank you for your help.  Here is what I did:

`sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`

returned an error: Unable to locate package linux-firmware-nonfree.  After checking, I discovered that linux-firmware-nonfree is not part of the saucy repository.  I edited /etc/apt/sources.list to include:

`deb http://us.archive.ununtu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse`

Then did 
`sudo apt-get update`
    then did 
`sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`
`power down`
`reboot`
Success